# Parsing String with Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a String which is formatted as such

`[dgdds,dfse][fsefsf,sefs][fsfs,fsef]`

How would I use Regex to quickly parse this to return an ArrayList with each value containing one "entry" as such?

```
ArrayList <String>:

0(String): [dgdds,dfse]

1(String): [fsefsf,sefs]

2(String): [fsfs,fsef]
```

Really stuck with this, any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `\[.*?\]` regex, which means: match a string starting with `[`, later zero or more characters (but as short as possible, not greedly, that's why the `?` in `.*?`), ending with `]`.

This works, you can test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/PoHSLM):

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
String input = "[dgdds,dfse][fsefsf,sefs][fsfs,fsef]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) 
{
    result.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
[[dgdds,dfse], [fsefsf,sefs], [fsfs,fsef]]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
String myData = "[dgdds,dfse][fsefsf,sefs][fsfs,fsef]";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myData
        .split("(?<=\\])")));

for (String s : list)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
[dgdds,dfse]
[fsefsf,sefs]
[fsfs,fsef]
```

This regex will use [look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) mechanism to split on each place after `]`.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this regex :
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\w*,\\w*\\]");

Answer (score 2):

Old, easy, awesome way :)

```
String s = "[dgdds,dfse][fsefsf,sefs][fsfs,fsef]";
        String[] token = s.split("]");
        for (String string : token) {
            System.out.println(string + "]");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do it in two passes:

(1) **Split out by the brackets** if it's just a 1D array (not clear in the question):

```
String s = "[dgdds,dfse][fsefsf,sefs][fsfs,fsef]";
String[] sArray = s.split("\\[|\\]\\[|\\]");
```

(2) **Split by the commas** if you want to also divide, say "dgdds,dfse"

```
sArray[i].split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split(regex)` function directly by escaping  `"]"`:  `"\\]"` and then use it as the `regex` for pattern matching:

```
String str = "[dgdds,dfse][fsefsf,sefs][fsfs,fsef]";
     String bal[] = str.split("\\]");

     ArrayList<String>finalList = new ArrayList<>();

     for(String s:bal)
     {
         finalList.add(s+"]");
     }
     System.out.println(finalList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split using this `(?:(?<=\])|^)(?=\[)` might work if there are nothing between `][`